# Are file contents deleted when a text file is opened in "ios::in|ios::out" mode?

Tags: c++, file-io, text-files, fstream, file-handling

I have red recently that when a text file is opened using `ios::out` mode then `ios::trunc` is available by default. So when i open a file using `ios::in|ios::out` mode, `ios::trunc` will be available automatically or not?
I think that contents will not be deleted because `ios::in` is also used and both the *get pointer* and *put pointer* will be initially pointing to the zeroth byte in the file.
Am i correct?

Comment: Did you try to do any research? [This page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open) explains everything you need to know.

Comment: You shouldn't have downvoted this question. I searched but unable to find solution.

Comment: Why I shouldn't have downvoted it? The way I see it: you didn't do any research, since it took me less than a minute, to find the page I linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `out` alone does imply `trunc`, `in|out` does not.  The full details are enumerated here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open

If you want to write to a file but not destroy the existing contents, you can also use `app` (which implies `out`).  Absent either `in` or `app`, any existing contents will be destroyed by `out`.